# Convert SQL database to a newer version

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

My new hosting has been having issues importing my wordpress database and are getting errors.

The current export is..

```
-- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.1.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

And apparently I need an SQL dump which is compatible with:

```
baseos | u741-vyqcbnevctcc@gukm1004.siteground.biz:~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.21-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

I no longer have access the old sever this was exported from so a bit stuck on what I can do. Any suggestions?

**Note: I'm not a developer myself so if you can keep replies as simple as possible that would help me a lot. Many thanks x**

Errors

```
baseos | u741-vyqcbnevctcc@gukm1004.siteground.biz:~/www/hitthefloor.com/public_html$ mysql -uum97phahmtkam -p db7xvunnykh5fd < hitthefloor__.sql --force
Enter password:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6561: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 7
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6574: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_blog_versions' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6575: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_blog_versions' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6576: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_blog_versions' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6577: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_blog_versions' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6587: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 17
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6610: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_blogs' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6611: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_blogs' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6612: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_blogs' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6613: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_blogs' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6623: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 10
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6639: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_commentmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6640: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_commentmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6641: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_commentmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6651: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 23
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6680: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_comments' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6681: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_comments' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6682: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_comments' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6784: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 18
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6808: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6809: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6810: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6811: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_lockouts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6821: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 17
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6844: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6845: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6846: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6847: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6857: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 14
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6877: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_temp' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6878: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_temp' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6879: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_temp' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6880: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_itsec_temp' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6890: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 17
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6913: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_links' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6914: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_links' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 6915: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_links' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7061: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 6
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7073: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_options' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7074: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_options' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7075: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_options' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7076: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_options' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7086: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 9
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7101: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_post_views' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7102: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_post_views' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7103: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_post_views' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7104: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_post_views' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7114: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 9
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7129: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7130: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7131: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7132: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7133: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7134: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7135: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7136: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7137: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7138: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7139: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7140: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7141: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7142: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7143: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7144: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7145: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7146: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7147: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7148: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7149: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7150: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7151: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7152: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7153: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7154: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7155: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7156: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7157: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7158: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7159: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7160: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7161: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7162: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7163: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7164: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7165: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7166: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7167: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7168: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7169: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7170: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7171: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7172: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7173: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7174: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7175: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7176: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7177: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7178: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7179: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7180: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7181: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7182: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7183: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7184: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7185: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7186: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7187: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7188: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7189: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7190: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7191: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7192: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7193: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7194: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7195: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7196: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7197: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7198: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7199: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7200: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7201: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7202: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7203: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7204: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7205: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7206: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7207: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7208: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7209: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7210: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7211: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7212: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7213: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7214: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7215: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7216: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7217: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7218: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_postmeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7228: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 31
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7265: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7266: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7267: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7268: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7269: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7270: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7271: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7272: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7273: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7274: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7275: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7276: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7277: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7278: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7279: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7280: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7281: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7282: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7283: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7284: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7285: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7286: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7287: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7288: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7289: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7290: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7291: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7292: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7293: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7294: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7295: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7296: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7297: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7298: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7299: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7300: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7301: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7302: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7303: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7304: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7305: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7306: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7307: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7308: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7309: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7310: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7311: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7312: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7313: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7314: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7315: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7316: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7317: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7318: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7319: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7320: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7321: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7322: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7323: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7324: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7325: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7326: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7327: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7328: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7329: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7330: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7331: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7332: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7333: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7334: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7335: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7336: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7337: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7338: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7339: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7340: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7341: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7342: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7343: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7344: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7345: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7346: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7347: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7348: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7349: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7350: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7351: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7352: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7353: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7354: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7355: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7356: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7357: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7358: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7359: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7360: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_posts' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7370: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 9
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7385: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_registration_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7386: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_registration_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7387: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_registration_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7388: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_registration_log' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7398: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 18
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7422: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_signups' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7423: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_signups' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7424: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_signups' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7425: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_signups' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7435: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 7
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7448: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_site' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7449: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_site' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7450: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_site' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7451: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_site' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7461: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 9
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7476: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_sitemeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7477: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_sitemeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7478: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_sitemeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7479: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_sitemeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7522: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 7
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7535: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_relationships' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7536: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_relationships' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7537: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_relationships' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7538: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_relationships' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7539: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_relationships' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7540: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_relationships' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7550: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 12
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7568: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7569: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7570: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7571: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7608: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 10
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7624: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_terms' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7625: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_terms' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7626: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_terms' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7627: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_terms' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7689: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 9
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7704: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_usermeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7705: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_usermeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7706: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_usermeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7707: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_usermeta' doesn't exist
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7717: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`compression`='tokudb_zlib'' at line 18
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7741: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_users' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7742: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_users' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7743: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_users' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 7744: Table 'db7xvunnykh5fd.htf_users' doesn't exist
```

Comment: May be you could tell us what the errors were?

Comment: Just added them to the main post for you

Comment: Well, looks like you used the TokuDB engine in your old database and it doesn't seem to be supported or properly configured in your new server. You'll have to edit your dump file and choose a supported engine I guess.